# How to calculate shadow position below arcing projectile in Isometric 2d tilebased grid?

Tags: unity, tilemap, isometric, grid, linear-algebra

I have an Isometric 2D grid-based tilemap, and am firing a projectile (at **Vector P1** in image below) from the player (at **Vector A**) to a location "above" a target location (at **Vector B**). This works mostly fine (see animation gif at bottom of post).

**How can I calculate the location of a shadow sprite? I've tried several usages of dot products and projections but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. How do I project a location from the projectile arc position **P1** down onto the AB line?**

[image: unity vectors]

The shadow should always be located along the line **AB**:

[image: line for shadow]

This is the closest I've gotten in the below animation:

[image: visual]

Here is some of the code for the above animation:

```csharp
private void Update()
{
    // ... other code for moving the flare sprite
    
    var A = new Vector2(_castFromLocation.x, _castFromLocation.y);
    var B = new Vector2(_hoverOverLocation.x, _hoverOverLocation.y);
    var P1 = new Vector2(_flare.transform.position.x, _flare.transform.position.y);
                
    var AB_ = B - A;
    var AP1_ = P1 - A;

    var dotProduct = Vector2.Dot(AB_, AP1_);
    var distanceAlongAB = dotProduct / AP1_.magnitude;

    _shadow.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_castFromLocation, _hoverOverLocation, distanceAlongAB);
}
```

Comment: You might find [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38692488/3064164) useful here.

Comment: That's definitely helpful, thank you! Though it uses a different physics approach modeling velocity/acceleration. Still hoping if I can get a similar effect similar using projection of position-vectors, and understand the linear algebra there a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple, scalable solution. There are several prerequisites to be clarified:

1. For the oblique throwing motion, it can be decomposed into the uniform linear motion of the x-axis and the vertical upward throwing motion of the y-axis.
2. The shadow is moving in a straight line with uniform speed.
3. The object is directly above the shadow, and the height conforms to the quadratic function, and the height is 0 at the start and end.

So we can **draw the shadow first**, and then draw the object through the position of the shadow, which is simpler.

```
private const float MOVE_DURATION = 2f;
private float moveTimeLeft = 0f;
private Vector3 from;
private Vector3 to;

private void Update()
{
    ...
    if(moveTimeLeft<=0) return;
    moveTimeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    var moveRate = 1 - moveTimeLeft/MOVE_DURATION;
    var shadowPosition = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, moveRate);
    _shadow.transform.position = shadowPosition;
}
public void StartMove(Vector3 fromSet, Vector3 toSet)
{
    from = fromSet;
    to = toSet;
    moveTimeLeft = MOVE_DURATION;
}
```

Here we assume that the moving time is fixed, and the shadow moves to the end at a constant speed according to this time.

Then let's deal with the height of the object, here we introduce a "normalized" quadratic function:
$$
y=-\left(2x-1\right)^{2}+1
$$

It looks like this:

[image]

When x represents the rate of movement, we can use it to calculate the height of the object.

```
private const float MOVE_DURATION = 2f;
private const float HIGHEST_HEIGHT= 2f;
private float moveTimeLeft = 0f;
private Vector3 from;
private Vector3 to;

private void Update()
{
    ...
    if(moveTimeLeft<=0) return;
    moveTimeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    var moveRate = 1 - moveTimeLeft/MOVE_DURATION;
    var shadowPosition = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, moveRate);
    _shadow.transform.position = shadowPosition;

    var height = − Mathf.Pow(2*moveRate−1,2) + 1;
    _flare.transform.position = shadowPosition + Vector3.up * height * HIGHEST_HEIGHT;
}
public void StartMove(Vector3 fromSet, Vector3 toSet)
{
    from = fromSet;
    to = toSet;
    moveTimeLeft = MOVE_DURATION;
}
```

Because the game is not the real world, you can draw the trajectory according to the effect you want. Here are some examples:

1. The shadow has a constant speed:

```
private const float shadowSpeed = 2f;
private float moveTimeMax = 0f;
private float moveTimeLeft = 0f;
public void StartMove(Vector3 fromSet, Vector3 toSet)
{
    from = fromSet;
    to = toSet;
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(from,to);
    moveTimeMax = distance / shadowSpeed;
    moveTimeLeft = moveTimeMax;
}
```

2. The maximum height of the object varies with the launch distance:

```
private float highestHeight = 0f;
private void Update()
{
    ...
    _flare.transform.position = shadowPosition + Vector3.up * height * highestHeight;
    ...
}
public void StartMove(Vector3 fromSet, Vector3 toSet)
{
    ...
    highestHeight = distance/2;
    ...
}
```

3. Objects are always launched at a 45 degree angle:

```
public void StartMove(Vector3 fromSet, Vector3 toSet)
{
    ...
    highestHeight = distance/4;
    ...
}
```

In general, if we give up the accurate calculation of physics such as gravity acceleration and velocity, things will be much simpler. We can directly give a motion curve and scale it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the x,y (but not height z) coords of the projectile.

Copy the terrain height z at this x,y coordinate.

In 3D space, your shadow is at x,y,z.

Project this using orthogonal projection to screen space X,Y.

In your terrain code, make sure you have a way to get the discrete grid X,Y given a 3D vector's x,y, and get the height given this X,Y coord, and translate that height into 3D amount (to scale).

Here's some pseudo code:

```
float x = _flare.transform.position.X;
float y = _flare.transform.position.Y;
float z = _terrain.GetHeight((int)x, int(y));

_shadow.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```